# How to show the special characters in text box when check box is selected

Tags: html, xml, wpf

I want to show special characters in the textbox.

The process is below:

1.First when We select check box named as `special characters`.Then below there will text box should agree for the special characters.

2.After selecting a checkbox,  type special characters in the textbox then it should agree.if not it must show an error message.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(textbox1.Text, @"[~`!@#$%^&*()+=|\\{}':;.,<>/?[\]""_-]")) return;
        textbox1.Text = string.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Alphabets and Numbers are not allowed");
    }
```